# Как в Laravel / PostgreSql сгруппировать таблицу

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Всем привет!
В Laravel 5.6 / PostgreSql9.6 нужно сгруппировать таблицу songs по полю title которых более одной
так работает:

```
$songsWithSimilarTitlesList = Song::orderBy('title', 'desc')
    ->select('title', DB::raw('count(*) as total_songs'))
    ->groupBy('title')
    ->get();
```

Но если добавить условие более 1:

```
$songsWithSimilarTitlesList = Song::orderBy('title', 'desc')
    ->select('title', DB::raw('count(*) as total_songs'))
    ->groupBy('title')
    ->having('total_songs', '>', 1)
    ->get();
```

То получаю ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "total_songs" does not exist LINE 1: ...tal_songs from "rt_songs" group by "title" having "total_son... ^ (SQL: select "title", count(*) as total_songs from "rt_songs" group by "title" having "total_songs" > 1 order by "title" desc)
```

А как правильно ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать метод `havingRaw`:

```
$songsWithSimilarTitlesList = Song::orderBy('title', 'desc')
    ->select('title', DB::raw('count(*) as total_songs'))
    ->groupBy('title')
    ->havingRaw('count(*) > 1')
    ->get();
```